# How to created signed AuthNRequest?

Tags: x509certificate, saml, saml-2.0, signing

I am interfacing with an IDP and have a basic AuthNRequest created as follows:

```xml
<samlp:AuthnRequest
  xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
  xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
  ID="IDTest1" 
  Version="2.0"
  IssueInstant="2013-03-04T09:21:59"
  AssertionConsumerServiceIndex="0"
  AttributeConsumingServiceIndex="0">
  <saml:Issuer>https://myapp.com/saml2/sp</saml:Issuer> 
 <samlp:NameIDPolicy
   AllowCreate="true"
   Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"/>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

IDP wants me send the request as signed. My questions are:

1. How do I set digest value?
2. How do I set Signature value?
3. For x509 certificate, I set the public key of my app. Correct?
4. What is the data that is used to compute any of the values? Is it my original auth request without Signature element?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @user1922049 : If u get the answer can u post that by editing ur question?

Comment: I have released a new edition of the book, covering OpenSAML V3
https://gumroad.com/l/a-guide-to-opensaml-v3

Answer (score 9):

Just to note that a lot of this is covered in the documentation:

[SAML metadata](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf).

To have the request signed you need to add something like this (normally found in the sp.xml):

```
<SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" WantAssertionsSigned="false"
                 protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
```

The signing key would look something like:

```
<KeyDescriptor use="signing">
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>
                MIIDWTC...CAkGgAwIBAgIEe+a+/uaSZCp5g2z+hRWRV+DyfQc9nO
            </ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</KeyDescriptor>
```

where the MII... is the public key.

As per @Stefan, it's much easier to use a library.

Answer (score 5):

SAML Authentication Request is an XML document. You can sign SAML Authentication Request just like signing any other XML document. There are, however, some restrictions:

1. The signature must be enveloped signature.
2. Before it is digested, the SAML Authentication Request must not be transformed by method other than enveloped signature transform and exclusive canonicalization transform.
3. The Signature element must contain only one Reference element.
4. The URI of the only Reference element must contain the value of the ID attribute of the signed SAML Authentication Request.
5. Before it is signed, the SignedInfo element must be canonicalize using exclusive canonicalization method.

You can read more detail the SAML Assertions and Protocols Specification (http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) in Section 5.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is inadequate!

The AuthRequest you're sending seems to be **REDIRECT** request where you will not see Digest, Signature and Certificate since all these details will be in URL as a parameter.

Try using **POST SSO** request, where you will see Digest, Signature and Certificate in SAML request.

### Some of the points:

#### Common

- Both IdP and SP should share their `Metadata`, which will have their basic configuration like id, signing algorithm, hashing method, public key etc.
- So, based on the contract between IdP you should hash and sign your request in your preferred programming language.

#### SP:

- You should encrypt using your public key.
- You should sign using your private key.
- You should encode your request using Base64.

#### IdP:

- They will identity using the public key in the request.
- They will respond back with encrypted and signed XML.
- You should decrypt and unsign the response.

#### Quick Links

1. [Official Doc about SAML 2.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.html)
2. [SAML Online Tool by OneLogin](https://www.samltool.com)

Comment: The URL parameter in HTTP-Redirect binding is just a Base64 encoded version of the same data. The question asks how to generate the signature, which is the same regardless of the binding type (not how to *send* the signature, which might differ).

Answer (score 3):

If your into constructing your own requests without any bigger frameworks around I can recommend OpenSAML. Its a library to help with the construction of SAML messages.

In my book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), this and more is explained in detail.

EDIT I have released a [new edition of the book](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), covering OpenSAML V3

[Here](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2012/11/signing-with-opensaml.html) is an example I wrote on signing SAML messages

[And one](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest.html) on how to dispatch AuthnRequests.

Answer (score 2):

Well things concerning security are never easy...
you sholud definetly check documentation Linked by @nzpcmad, as well as
[SAML2 profiles](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) (look for WB SSO - Web Browser Single Sign On).

For Java OpenSaml is indeed one of easiest solutions.

Answer (score 1):

A pitfall seems to be that with HTTP-Redirect Binding the Signature is transported by additional URL-Parameters and not part of the SAMLRequest value, e.g. https://my-idp.com/login?SAMLRequest=nVNN...%3D&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2F04%2Fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256&Signature=QZ64...%3D%3D