# Which public key (SP or remote IDP) to use while signing SAML request

Tags: public-key-encryption, saml-2.0, signing

I am trying to configure my application (SP) to work with remote IDP. The IDP provided me with a certificate to configure with SP. For SAML request, do I use SP's public key or IDP's? 
Also, where can I find good resources to study SAML in detail (apart from the oasis formal documents). The tutorials that I find are very simplistic (i.e. they just describe that SP goes to IDP and then it is redirected back but do not go into detail on SAML messages). The oasis documents are confusing.
Thanks for any answers

Comment: do you need to sign the request at all?

Comment: The IDP requires me to sign. From the security point of view, I understand it is not really necessary

Comment: ok, just checking! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks from these two sources that you should sign with your (SP's) private key and share the associated public key with the IdP so they can verify the signature.

- [How to Create Signed AuthnRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255706/how-to-created-signed-authnrequest)
- http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-metadata-2.0-os.pdf (p.25)

Answer (score 12):

Signing is done using private keys - not public keys.

So, if the SAML request needs to be signed, SP must use its private key for it. Also, a certificate containing SP's public key should be given to the IdP to validate the signature.

The reason for IdP providing you its certificate is for SP to validate the signed SAML responses sent by the IdP.

Comment: before reading this answer, I somehow assumed that it's always the party's private key. but what I don't understand is, if SP signs the request with its private key, how can IdP validate it with the public key? AFAIU the asymmetrical cryptography, it's the other way around. Any one with the public key can encrypt a message, while it's only the private key holder(s) that can decrypt it

Comment: @asgs Please refer: https://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/digital-signature.

Comment: thanks @drox That was helpful. Another article that made it even clearer is this [CGI's whitepaper](https://www.cgi.com/files/white-papers/cgi_whpr_35_pki_e.pdf) which explains the fact that the Asymmetrical Encryption can be used either ways depending on what purpose needs to be solved. If confidentiality of message is required, public key is used for encryption and private key for decryption; if authenticity of message is required, private key to sign the message and public key to confirm if the signature matches with the message.